# How to execute tcl/tk scripts from icc shell?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to execute a Synopsys ICC commmands :

```
gui_set_flat_hierarchy_color -color 8
```

from a button press with the help of a `TCL/TK` script. 
The script is as follows:

```
proc push_button {} {
    gui_set_flat_hierarchy_color -color 8
}

button .but -text "Push Me" -command "push_button"
pack .but
```

I run the script with "exec wish myprog.tcl" from `icc_shell`.
But i press the button, i get following error :

```
invalid command name "gui_set_flat_hierarchy_color"
     while executing
"gui_set_flat_hierarchy_color -color 8"
     (procedure "push_button" line 3)
     invoked from within
"push_button"
     invoked from within
".but invoke"
     ("uplevel" body line 1)
     invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list $w invoke]"
     (procedure "tk::ButtonUp" line 22)
     invoked from within
"tk::ButtonUp .but"
     (command bound to event)
```

Answer (score 0):

The command gui_set_flat_hierarchy_color might only be available after you started the GUI.

Comment: Yes sir, I am keeping GUI open to notice colour change. But I am getting "invalid command" error when push button from my gui. I am able to open gui from ICC shell, but i am unable to execute the icc commands used in my script. KIndly help.